# Why is the label in my custom table cell can not show until clicked on the row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

What I need to implement is an custom table view cell which have an additional label on the other side of the cell.

I do the followings.

1.drag an UILabel to the Cell's contentView as follows.

[image]

2.create a custom table cell class named NoteTableCell extends the UITableViewCell class

3.connect the IBOutlet named "timeLabel" in the NoteTableCell class to the Label.

4.in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method,

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NoteTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[NoteTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Note * note = [notelist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = note.title;
cell.timeLabel.text = note.time;      //set the timeLabel

return cell;
```

Everytime I create a new note and return back, the label content didn't show up until I select the row , do I miss something here?

Comment: Can you just use for time being cell.textLabel.text = @"xyz"; and see your all rows populating with this xyz !! If you are still getting same issue then change cell.textlabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; Try this and let me know.

Comment: You need to give more detail about what you're doing when you "create a new note and return back". There's nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Actually I am creating a same app "Notes" as the one pre-installed on Iphone. So every time I use a detail view to create a new Note and return back to the table view through a navigation controller. We could see the note title and create time in the row cell. I am using the delegate to passed the note data back. I am pretty sure the data is no problem. But the additional timeLabel just can't show up until I select the row

Comment: @Vish. It's not about the default cell textLabel. the default cell textLable is fine. But the Label I added has issue. And can't solve it even I change the colour as you suggest

Comment: @xuqin1019 have you connected your outlet of label in your custom cell class?

Comment: Ok so I can't ask for the code but you can compare with this tutorial and figure out whats wrong in your code zhttp://www.verious.com/article/using-xcode-storyboards-to-build-dynamic-table-views-with-prototype-table-view-cells/ . Let me know all the best

Comment: @Vish still can not figure out where is the problem . And this time I just use a UITableViewCellStyleValue1 style for the default cell instead. And set the time info in the cell's detailTextLabel. this works pretty nice.

Comment: @xuqin1019 Ok Great.If you mark the comment with the link helpful it will be good for others to find relevant solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = (NoteTableCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NoteTableCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];;
}
```

Comment: and I didn't use any nib file , I am using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe set the cell backgroundcolor is equal to label textcolor,so you can't see it.When touch the cell,cell backgroundcolor change,you see the text.

Comment: thank . But I don't think so ,I just use the default configuration. the cell background color is white and the text color is black.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a cell prototype in your storyboard, and give it an identifier of "Cell"? (With an upper-case C and the rest of the letters lower-case)